# Refresh power query before power pivot

Tags: powerquery, powerpivot

I have power query collect data from external file , then some process done and load to data model where i made many power pivot from them I made final report form ,
this report send to employee where they only see on sheet report , just extract source file and press refresh all.[text](https://stackoverflow.com)
the problem is when I extract new source file some pivot table filters disappear , so I have to manually reset them

[image]

[image]

I think that the problem data added to data model before query finish , so some column filter doesn't exist , i need to delay refresh power pivot after power query

Answer (score 1):

In the Power Query properties, untick the box that enables background refresh.

With background refresh, PQ will start the refresh and the PivotTable will refresh before the PQ refresh is finished.

Disable background refersh, so that the PivotTable refresh only starts after the PQ refresh has completed.

[image]